# Dynamic Animations?

Tags: javascript, html, animation

So I'm trying to make this div animation a little more realistic by implementing a "physics engine" that slightly resembles how it would actually accelerate and decelerate... kinda...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gio is Fay</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sliding.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="button">
    <h5>Click me!</h5>
    <h4>HARDER!</h4>
    </div>

    <div id="moving"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var sliding = document.getElementById("moving");
        var margin = sliding.style.marginTop | 100;

        var speeds = [0.5, 1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 8, 5, 3, 1];
        var length = speeds.length;

        sliding.onclick = move;

        function move() {
            window.log("Herro!");
            for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                var x = speeds[i];
                margin += x * 5;
                sliding.style.marginTop = margin + "px";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the div, unsurprisingly, nothing happens. I put in an alert box to tell me whether the function was being triggered, and apparently it wasn't. Or at least the alert never showed up.  Not sure why. No errors in the console. Help?

Comment: `window.log =/= console.log`.

Comment: just a quick note: if you want to 'emulate' physics, use formulas. not arrays with numbers...

Comment: What you are doing already comes with CSS for free.  For some examples, see http://easings.net

Comment: Short of a physics engine, you might try using easings. Here's one library to check out: https://greensock.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code, and everything but window.log() "worked", so I'm not sure why you weren't getting any results at all.

This really isn't the best method to animate.  You should use requestAnimationFrame(), which works a lot like a setTimeout() but is optimized for animation.  When I got your code working, you don't see an animation at all because you have only 17 frames, and those 17 passes through the for loop happen SUPER fast.  So look into requestAnimationFrame() for animating with js.  Here is what your code would look like implementing that change:

```
var sliding = document.getElementById("moving");
var margin = sliding.style.marginTop | 10;

var speeds = [0.5, 1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 8, 5, 3, 1];
var length = speeds.length;
var frame = 0;

sliding.onclick = function () {
  frame = 0;
  requestAnimationFrame(move);
}

function move() {
  var x = speeds[frame];
  margin += x;
  sliding.style.marginTop = margin + "px";
  if (frame < length)
    requestAnimationFrame(move);
  frame++;
}
```

You should also reconsider your method for changing the rate.  I would use trig functions.  That way you could easily change the duration and distance that the div moves.  Here is an example of that, feel free to use it.  You can run this snippet to see what it looks like.

```js
var sliding = document.getElementById("moving");
var margin = sliding.style.marginTop | 10;

// a few settings for our animation
var theta = 0.0;    //in radians
var distance = 100; //in pixels
var duration = 1;   //in seconds
var frameRate = 60; //fps
var down = false;   //a switch so we can move up and down, we are starting in the up position

sliding.onclick = function () {
  if (down)
    //if we need to go up, we start at 1 (cos(PI) = -1)
    theta = Math.PI;
  else
    //otherwise we start at 0
    theta = 0.0;
  
  //flip it
  down = !down;
  
  //and away we go
  requestAnimationFrame(move);
}

function move() {
  //the margin is determined with cos
  margin = (-1 * Math.cos(theta) + 1) * distance + 10;
  //and set
  sliding.style.marginTop = margin + "px";
  //our theta advances
  theta += (Math.PI) / frameRate / duration;
  //and we continue if we are not at either end
  if ((down && theta <= Math.PI) || (!down && theta <= Math.PI * 2))
    requestAnimationFrame(move);
}
```

```css
#moving {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #047;
  color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="moving">DIV</div>
```

And finally, jQuery has this stuff built in so you don't have to worry about reinventing the wheel, so look in to that.  I hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, I know jQuery does all this, but I'm trying to learn how to do it myself. Why? I dunno. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

first of all, as mentioned.  window.log isnt a function.  I do get that error in the console. You will also need to set the position of your `moving` div to be relative to see it move.

Here is a fiddle of your code (with my modifications)

http://jsfiddle.net/404xk2fo/

when I click on the red div it will instantly disappear off the screen because it's moving quite a bit.  Lower the multiplication factor, and it will stay on the screen but still instantly move.  The problem is you are trying to animate in this loop without any kind of timer.  Executing this code in a loop is so fast that your animation is going to happen instantly.

check out this webpage for some examples on how to do smooth animations in javascript.  the key is using `requestAnimationFrame`

http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/

I added a really simple example of `requestAnimationFrame`  http://jsfiddle.net/j4x9dctq/

I'm using a little jquery to select the div. I just prefer jquery syntax.  you can use native javascript if you prefer.